# JS for Loop for XMLHttpRequest can't proceed all requests

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, xmlhttprequest

I just challenge myself with `FreeCodeCamp TwitchTV API` challenge. Please take a glimpse at this code:

```
function forTwitchList() {
  var twitchers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
  for (var i = 0; i < twitchers.length; i++) {
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + twitchers[i] + '?client_id=myproperclientIDhere');
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
      var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
      console.log(ourData);
    };
    ourRequest.send();
  }
}


forTwitchList();
```

First of all, I wanted to check if I can write off console.log with all of my `XMLHttpRequest` (tried to use for loop for every `XMLHttpRequest`). I've figured out that it just doesn't work - I get different results by every `forTwitchList()` function invoke, for example for the last invoke I get the following message:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload"

It applies for 3 twitchers Array elements, for 5 others I've actually get the called Objects, but these refer to only the last element of the twitchers Array, `noob2ninjas`. I mean, I've got 5 called objects, but the name of all of this if `noob2ninjas`, while it should call names from twitchers Array.

But the point is every time I recall this function, there are different results (for example 2 Uncaught Syntax errors and 6 results, all refers to last element of Array).

However, I've figured out that when I change `JSON.parse(**ourRequest**.responseText)` to `JSONparse(**this**.responseText)` [7th line of code) it works out properly. I just don't know why.

EDIT:
@epascarello Yes, this is the exact code.
@Jaromanda X Why is it work like that? Shouldn't it execute the command at first, and once it happen go through remaining code (I mean the other element of the loop)? Why moving the body of my for loop to a separate function should works?

So as I said before, I finally found out how to make my function working (but still don't know why - see above). Now my code looks like this:

```
function forTwitchList() {
var twitchers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
for (var i=0; i<twitchers.length; i++) {
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + twitchers[i] + '?client_id=myclientidcode');
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
        var ourData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (ourData.stream === null) {
            twitchList.innerHTML += '<div class="twitchentries">' + '<a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitch.tv/' + twitchers[i] + '">' + ourData._links.channel + '</a>' + '<p>This twitch is offline</p>' + '</div>' + '<br>';            
        } else {
            twitchList.innerHTML += '<div class="twitchentries">' + '<a target="_blank" href="' + ourData.stream.channel.url + '">' + ourData.stream.channel.url + '</a>' + '<p>This twitch is online</p><p>Streamed game:' + ourData.stream.game + '</p>' + '</div>' + '<br>';
        }        
        console.log(ourData);
    };
    ourRequest.send();
}   
}
forTwitchList();
```

So I've tried to add divs (inside my for loop) which contain info about channel link and displayed game. It's working fine for online channels ("else" mark in for loop) - offline games haven't "ourData.stream.channel.url" property, so I've come up with idea of concatenate direct classic link "https://www.twitch.tv/" with twitchers[i] value, as it contains the name of channel.

My problem is that for loop can't figure out what [i] value is - as it says, it's undefined. I can't figure out why - I've defined the twitchers Array inside my forTwitchList() function. When I put the exact number instead of [i] mark, I get the proper result, but the result is the same of every Array element, so I got the same channel link for every element, what is incorrect.

Comment: And that is the exact code?

Comment: by the time the first request even has a chance to fire, `ourRequest` will be the value of the LAST request, as it will for all requests - move the body of your for loop to a separate function - or as you have found out, `this` in the onload callback will be the "correct" `ourRequest` object

Comment: I've added and edit to my problem.